# Can't play sound in my java game

Tags: java, audio

```
package com.first.serious.main.controls;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;


public class AudioPlayer {

private Clip clip;


public AudioPlayer(String path){
    try{

        AudioInputStream AIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(AIS);
        AudioInputStream audiostream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);

        /* AudioFormat baseFormat = AIS.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                                                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                                                    16,baseFormat.getChannels(),
                                                    baseFormat.getChannels()*2,
                                                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),false);

        AudioInputStream DAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodeFormat,AIS);*/

        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audiostream);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void play(){
    if(clip == null) return;
    stop();
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}


public void stop(){
    if(clip.isRunning()) clip.stop();
}

public void close(){
    stop();
    clip.close();
}
}
```

Honestly, I just copied the code because I am a complete beginner in game developing. Already had two sets of code, the commented lines are from the first.

I used it in this class for mouseinputs

```
package com.first.serious.main.controls;

import com.first.serious.main.Shooter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MouseInput implements MouseListener{

   private Shooter game;
   private AudioPlayer deadsound;


   public MouseInput(Shooter game){
       this.game = game;
      deadsound = new AudioPlayer("/res/sounds/deadsound2.mp3");
   }
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    int mx = me.getX();
    int my = me.getY();
    //System.out.println(mx + " "  + my);
    if(game.state.equals("menu")){
        if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 200 && my < 280){
            deadsound.play();
            game.state = "game";
        }else
         if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 460 && my < 540){
            System.exit(0);
        }else
          if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 330 && my < 410){
              game.state = "help";
          }
    }
    if(game.state.equals("Dead")){
       // System.out.println("dead");
        if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 260 && my < 340){
            game.Score = 0;
            game.state = "game";
        }else
        if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 390 && my < 470){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    if(game.state.equals("Upgrade")){
        if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 200 && my < 280){
            game.upgradectr = 0;
            game.player.XX += 0.5f;
            game.state2++;
            game.state = "game";
        }else
        if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 330 && my < 410){
            game.upgradectr = 0;
            game.getControl().Vy -= 1f;
            game.state2++;
            game.state = "game";
        }else
        if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 460 && my < 540){
             if(game.state2==05||game.state2==10||game.state2==20){
                game.upgradectr = 0;
                game.player.a += 2;
                game.state2++;
                game.state = "game";
            }else{   
                game.upgradectr = 0;
                System.out.println(game.upgradectr);
                game.getControl().reload -= 2;
                game.state2++;
                System.out.println(game.state2);
                game.state = "game";
             }
        }

    }else
    if(game.state.equals("help")){
        if(mx > 60 && mx < 330 && my > 460 && my < 540){
            game.state = "menu";
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
}
```

}

and then get these errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
at com.first.serious.main.controls.AudioPlayer.<init>(AudioPlayer.java:17)
at com.first.serious.main.controls.MouseInput.<init>(MouseInput.java:15)
at com.first.serious.main.Shooter.init(Shooter.java:75)
at com.first.serious.main.Shooter.run(Shooter.java:670)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't absolutely know what is the exact problem. I have the following jar libraries: mp3spi1.9.5.jar, jl1.0.1.jar and, tritonus_share.jar. Please help. Thank you.

[directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATt18.png)

Please see the directories link for reference. thanks!. Realized the problem now, but haven't fully understood.
I'm sorry guys, but my problem now is, how can I access the files from the sound folder while my java file is in the controls folder. I tried putting the file inside where the java file is and it worked. But I want my files to be organized as much as I could. Please Help thank you.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream(path)` returns `null` if it can't find the path. See the [DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Comment: if you get that kind of error and don't know what it means, stop fiddling around with third party libraries, put creating games on a hold and first learn the basics.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have encoded the correct path of the file, if there would be a mistake, ot might be just the ' / ' but I have already tried both but still get the same results.

Comment: At first, I wantes to finish the game without any kind of imports such as images and sounds, but obviously, irony hits now. If I would not get past this, I might not include sounds anymore.